# Testing Scale Up versus Scale Out in the cloud

Tags: load-testing

This is my first post so do forgive me if I am no adhering properly to the correct site etiquette.

I am currently doing a project to test Scale Up Versus Scale Out on Web Applications in the cloud. Ideally I would like to test this on 2 Cloud solutions and compare and contrast the two. The options I am currently looking are Windows Azure, AWS or Google Apps. I have currently subscribed to Windows Azure free subscription.

To do this I am going to have to deploy some sort of load testing software to test the web applications. can you make any suggestions which load testing solution are the best to do this across the 2 different clouds and how I can set this up to get the best possible results for both solutions? I have read on here that LoadStorm is quite good but would that allow me to Scale Up V Scale out or would I be restricted to the load test features provided in the software? I was also thinking of using JMeter but have read that this is difficult to deploy in Azure.

Some of the questions I would like to answer are:

- Do 4 small core instance of  1.75GB perform better than 1 large core
  4 core(7GB) instance?
- Is it possible to use the same application on both clouds?
- What are the best metrics to use when comparing Scale Up versus Scale Out?

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If your scaling solution uses DNS load balancing to send load to new servers dynamically, make sure that your load testing solution caches DNS lookups correctly. Otherwise, your load will not be directed at new servers as they come online. I'll suggest that you look at our load testing software (Web Performance Load Tester) for your testing -- the LITE version is free, can generate unlimited load and handles DNS load balancing correctly (disclaimer: I work there).  Hope that helps!